# How to create dummy variables when a row belongs to multiple categories?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the below df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : np.arange(5),
              'cat': ['a|b|c','a|c', 'c|d','e|a|c', 'b|a']
             })
```

My objective is to get the dummy variables for all the cats **without using a for loop**. Below the outcome expected:

```
    id  cat     cat_a   cat_b   cat_c   cat_d   cat_e
0   0   a|b|c   1.0     1.0     1.0     0.0     0.0
1   1   a|c     1.0     0.0     1.0     0.0     0.0
2   2   c|d     0.0     0.0     1.0     1.0     0.0
3   3   e|a|c   1.0     0.0     1.0     0.0     1.0
4   4   b|a     1.0     1.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
```

Note: the below code produces the desired outcome but using `df.itertuples()`

```
cats = ['a','b','c','d','e']
zero_matrix = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(df), len(cats))), columns=cats)

for idx,*_,c in df.itertuples():
    cat_idx = zero_matrix.columns.get_indexer(c.split('|'))
    zero_matrix.iloc[idx, cat_idx ] = 1

df.join(zero_matrix.add_prefix('cat_'))
```

Pandas 0.23.4

Python 3.7

Comment: Use `df = df.join(df['app'].str.get_dummies(',').add_prefix('cat_'))`

Comment: Thanks @jezrael could not  find it before  perhaps due to ambigous question header.